# Error while build with java 16 and gradle 7.0

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i tried to build my project with gradle and java 16.

While building the project i get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: invalid source release: 16
```

Does anyone has an idea how i can fix it?